# Populate or fill all field using ajax in yii2

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, yii2

I want to populate all fields using ajax in yii2 when i give an input of Email ID and click on button than the username and all details should be fetch from mysql database and fill in the fields using jquery. my code are below.

signup.php

```
    <?php

                        $form = ActiveForm::begin([
                                    'options' => ['name' => 'membershipForm', 'autocomplete' => "off", 'id' => "formajax"],
                                    'action' => ['']
                        ]);
                        ?>
<div class="row">
                      <div class="col-sm-6">
                          <?= $form->field($model, 'email', ['options' => ['name' => 'Email']]) ?>
                          <span id="email-info" class="info"></span>
                      </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <?= $form->field($model, 'username')->textInput() ?>
                            <span id="username-info" class="info"></span>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <!-- Auto Popupulate -->
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <?= Html::submitButton('Check If Already a Member', ['class' => 'btn btn-warning', 'name' => 'populate-button', 'id' => 'PopupulateData', 'type' => 'submit']) ?>
                                 <!-- <input type="submit" value="Check If Already a Member" /> -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- End -->


                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <?= $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput() ?>
                            <span id="password-info" class="info"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <?= $form->field($model, 'first_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
                            <span id="first_name-info" class="info"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <?= $form->field($model, 'last_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
                            <span id="last_name-info" class="info"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <?=
                            $form->field($model, 'dob')->label('Date of Birth')->widget(
                                    DatePicker::className(), [
                                'inline' => false,
                                'clientOptions' => [
                                    'autoclose' => true,
                                    'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd'
                                ]
                            ]);
                            ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <?= $form->field($model, 'gender')->dropDownList(Yii::$app->commonUtility->getGenderDropdown(), ['prompt' => '(Select Gender)', 'options']) ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <?= $form->field($model, 'country')->dropDownList(Yii::$app->commonUtility->getCountryDropdown(), ['prompt' => '(Select Country)', 'options' => ['India' => ['selected' => true]]]) ?>
                            <span id="country-info" class="info"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!--Added by Exabit-->
                <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <?= $form->field($model, 'address')->textarea(['rows' => 6]) ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <!--Ended-->

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <?= $form->field($model, 'city')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
                            <span id="city-info" class="info"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <?= $form->field($model, 'state')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
                            <span id="state-info" class="info"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <?= $form->field($model, 'zip')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
                            <span id="zip-info" class="info"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <?= $form->field($model, 'phone')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <?= $form->field($model, 'mobile')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
                            <span id="mobile-info" class="info"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <?= $form->field($model, 'organization')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>



                    <input type="checkbox" name="terms_condition" value="terms&condition" checked=""> Yes, I agree with <a href="<?= Url::toRoute('/site/'); ?>" target="_blank">Terms & Conditions</a>
                    <span id="terms_condition-info" class="info"></span>

                    <!--                    <div clas="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <button id="rzp-button1" class="btn btn-warning">Pay</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>  -->
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <?= Html::submitButton('Pay', ['class' => 'btn btn-warning', 'name' => 'signup-button', 'id' => 'MemberShipbutton']) ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Populate data Javacript

```
$("#PopupulateData").on("click", function(event){

 var form = $('form[id="formajax"]');
  event.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
       type: "post",
  dataType: 'json',
  url: 'formajax1',});
});
```

This is in my SiteController.php

```
 public function actionFormajax1(){
  // return $this->render('formajax');
  $sql ="SELECT email,first_name,last_name FROM member";
  $formajax1 = Member::findBySql($sql)
  -all();
  Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
  if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
    $data = Yii::$app->request->post();
    // $searchname= explode(":", $data['searchname']);
    // $searchby= explode(":", $data['searchby']);
    $email = $data['email'];
    $first_name= $data['first_name'];
    $first_name= $data['first_name'];
    $responsedata = // your logic;
    \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    return [
        'responsedata' => $responsedata,
        'formajax1' => $formajax1,
    ];
  }
  }
```

Please let me know how to do it as this is new to me.. Thank you

Comment: Where is your error? You can find on the internet a lot of tutorial which helps you how to make an ajax call on yii2.

Comment: this code is not working. as it is not showing any error. If you know the solution than ping me back. thanks

Comment: I need to know where your code is breaking, for example post a var_dump($data) in you controller. In your js file you must do something if ajax success, after url try: ,success: function (response) { alert(response); }

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: I think you're trying to parse json data twice.

Comment: I am unable to fetch my input of the email id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You don't need do that all manually, you can simply use **Pjax**, It helps
>   you do similar things automaticly  (Updates form fields without
>   reloading...).

You can find documentation of Pjax by the link: 
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-pjax.html

**NoteController.php**:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Note();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save())
    {
        return $this->render('edit', [
            'model' => $model
        ]);
    }

    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

**create.php**

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\modules\notes\models\Note*/
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>

<div class="note-form">
<?php yii\widgets\Pjax::begin(['id' => 'new_note']) ?>
<?php 
    $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'method' => 'post',
        'action' => ['note/create'],         
        'options' => ['data-pjax' => true]
    ]); 
?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'note')->textarea(['rows' => 6]) ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton('Create', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>

</div>
```

**edit.php**

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\modules\notes\models\Note*/
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>

<div class="note-form">
<?php yii\widgets\Pjax::begin(['id' => 'new_note']) ?>
<?php 
    $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'method' => 'post',
        'action' => ['note/create'],         
        'options' => ['data-pjax' => true]
    ]); 
?>

<?= 
    $form
        ->field($model, 'id')
        ->hiddenInput()
        ->label(false); 
?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'note')->textarea(['rows' => 6]) ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton('Update', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
</div>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>

</div>
```

Something like this example possible do in your case also.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $("#PopupulateData").on("click", function(event){

     // var form = $('form[id="formajax"]');
      event.preventDefault();
      var email = $("#email").val();
      var first_name = $("#first_name").val();
      var last_name = $("#last_name").val();
// console.log("Success");
     // var form = document.getElementById("form-ajax");
     // form.attr('action', '$ajax_info');
     // form.$("#you_button_id").on("submit", form_submit, false);
     //var valNew = bounced.split("|");
            // $('#first_name').value;
            // $('#last_name').value;
            //$('#email').value;
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST", url: "formajax1",
         dataType: 'json',
         data: {
           email : email,
           first_name : first_name,
           last_name : last_name,

         },
         async: true,
         success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
             if(response != ''){
                 var json_obj = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(response));
                 console.log(json_obj);
                 console.log("Success");
                            }
             }

       })

     });
```

Site Controller is

```
public function actionFormajax1(){
  $formajax1 = Member::find()
  ->all();
  if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
      $return = [];
      $data = Yii::$app->request->post();
      // print_r($data);exit;

          // $username = $data['username'];
          $email = $data['email'];
          // $password = $data['password'];
          $first_name = $data['first_name'];
          $last_name = $data['last_name'];
          // $dob = $data['dob'];
          // $gender = $data['gender'];
          // $country = $data['country'];
          // $city = $data['city'];
          // $state = $data['state'];
          // $zip = $data['zip'];
          // $phone = $data['phone'];
          // $mobile = $data['mobile'];
          // $organization = $data['organization'];
          // $address = $data['address'];

          // $return['username'] = $username;
          $return['email'] = $email;
          // $return['password'] = $password;
          $return['first_name'] = $first_name;
          $return['last_name'] = $last_name;
          // $return['dob'] = $dob;
          // $return['gender'] = $gender;
          // $return['country'] = $country;
          // $return['city'] = $city;
          // $return['state'] = $state;
          // $return['zip'] = $zip;
          // $return['phone'] = $phone;
          // $return['mobile'] = $mobile;
          // $return['organization'] = $organization;
          // $return['address'] = $address;

      // $session = Yii::$app->session;


      echo json_encode($return);
  }
}
```

Now the issue is I am unable to fetch my input from email Id